# Is there a jQuery datatables - spring integration example

Tags: java, jquery, spring, datatables

I would like to make my jQuery to Spring Controller integration very smooth such that I can have a controller method defined as such:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/api")
public class DataTablesController {

    //could be GET or POST
    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    DataTablesResponse getData(@RequestBody DataTablesRequest dtReq, HttpServletResponse respnose) {
        .....
        DataTablesResponse response = new DataTablesResponse(dtReq.getEcho());
        .....
        return response;
    }
}
```

Is there an example of such an implementation that I can find somewhere? I have scoured google and this forum, but could not find anything close to this.

Comment: Please check if this link concerns to your question....http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/2456/datatables-spring-mvc-support/p1

Comment: Thanks - I was trying to go a step further than in the link by converting all the data passed in by JQuery into a bean `(@RequestBody DataTablesRequest)`. It does seem like there is nothing available - so I will write it by myself and post it back here.

Comment: Here's a [solution](http://java-juice.tumblr.com/post/13102234732/datatables-spring-mvc-integration) which provides a seamless integration between Datatables and Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and found this on github: 
https://github.com/yellowtrolley/RooDataTablesHibernate

It looks pretty promising.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this](https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables):

Example:

```
@RestController
public class UserRestController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @JsonView(DataTablesOutput.View.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/data/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public DataTablesOutput<User> getUsers(@Valid DataTablesInput input) {
        return userRepository.findAll(input);
    }
}
```

Maven artifact:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.github.darrachequesne</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-datatables</artifactId>
     <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a class called TableData which I return in the @ResponseBody:

```
public class TableData {

/**
 * @param data      The array of data
 */
public TableData(List data) {
    this.data = data;
}

/**
 * The data.  This will be converted to a JSON array of "data: ".  
 */
private List data;

/** Values for server side processing */
private Integer draw;
private Long recordsTotal;
private Long recordsFiltered;
```